# Spring Boot - Unable to view webpages with controller and configurations setup

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am unable to view any files in Spring Boot application. I have Spring Boot Servlet Initializer class loading my class properly, and I have a controller mapping to that URL. I know because I can see it in the log.

WebConfig.java

```
package com.project.LNUProject.config;

import com.project.LNUProject.utils.ViewNames;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project.LNUProject.config")
@Slf4j
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // == constants ==
    public static final String RESOLVER_PREFIX = "/WEB-INF/view/";
    public static final String RESOLVER_SUFFIX =".jsp";

    // == bean methods
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix(RESOLVER_PREFIX);
        viewResolver.setSuffix(RESOLVER_SUFFIX);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        log.info("registry add properly");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName(ViewNames.HOME);
    }
}
```

DevTrainingController.java

```
package com.project.LNUProject.Controller;

import com.project.LNUProject.utils.Mappings;
import com.project.LNUProject.utils.ViewNames;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

    @Slf4j
    @Controller
    public class DevTrainingController implements CRUDController{
        @Override
        @GetMapping(Mappings.DEV_TRAINING_TABLE)
        public String table() {
            return ViewNames.DEV_TRAINING_TABLE;
        }

        @Override
        public String edit() {
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        public String delete() {
            return "";
        }

        @GetMapping("/")
        public String home() {
            log.info("Home template map");
            return ViewNames.HOME;
        }
    }
```

The logs says

2018-10-22 21:09:32,974 [main] [INFO ] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/DevTrainingTable],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.project.LNUProject.Controller.DevTrainingController.table()
2018-10-22 21:09:32,977 [main] [INFO ] 
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}"
 onto public java.lang.String com.project.LNUProject.Controller.DevTrainingController.home()

...

2018-10-22 21:10:19,837 [main] [INFO ] com.project.LNUProject.config.WebConfig - registry add properly

However, when I go to http://localhost:8080/LNU-Project/, it's a page 404 error. Here is a link to my code on [github](https://github.com/rjpruitt16/LNU-Project/tree/master/WEB)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the module is called WEB, so it was map to  http://localhost:8080/WEB/